# Spring Cloud Config Server fallback for multiple repositories

Tags: java, spring-boot, bitbucket, spring-cloud-config-server

We are using spring cloud config server backed by bitbucket for config files. We have configured multiple repositories in application.yml of config server. We want to make it available even if bitbucket is down. We are looking for a solution that can cache config repositories and in case bitbucket is down it can still be able to serve properties of different repositories.
Below is my application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@bitbucket.org:config1.git
          ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
          privateKey: ${PEM}
          repos:
            service1:
              uri: git@bitbucket.org:config2.git
              ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
              privateKey: ${PEM}
            service2:
              uri: git@bitbucket.org:config3.git
              ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
              privateKey: ${PEM}
```

I have tried setting up `spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir` but it clones only the base config repo. How can we make config server to serve from local if bitbucket is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `basedir` property is the only way out. This is how we use that :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@bitbucket.org:config1.git
          ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
          privateKey: ${PEM}
          basedir: /home/user/config1-repo
          repos:
            service1:
              uri: git@bitbucket.org:config2.git
              ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
              privateKey: ${PEM}
              basedir: /home/user/config2-repo
            service2:
              uri: git@bitbucket.org:config3.git
              ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
              privateKey: ${PEM}
              basedir: /home/user/config3-repo
```

How did you try to reproduce the scenario where git is not available and forcing the config server to fetch the properties from local server path. I suggest you create the local path. And using git-bash clone the config repo inside your local repo directory. For example in this case go inside `/home/user/localRepo` and clone your config git repo there. Ensure to have all the files and folder be cloned properly.

Then try to reproduce the git not available scenario and check if your config server MS is able to fetch properties from local dir. This is the only way out for fallback.

Comment: We faced an issue with bitbucket recently when it was down and our applications' new replicas were not able to fetch config. I am looking for basedir property for multiple repositories

Comment: @SumitKumar : Can you show how you are configuring the basedir property in your application.yaml file. I suggest you clone the config-repo  in your basedir folder. I think you faced the problem with new replicas and not with existing replicas. So you can try my approach which will ensure that even for the first search try if it fails it will pick from your local basedir.

Comment: I have added the way you described but in that directory I can only see the config1 repo files, I want to solve it for multiple repositories

Comment: @SumitKumar : You need to have a basedir for every repo that you use individually. And you need to clone the repos to corresponding local basedirs .  I have edited my application.yaml snapshot. refer to that.

Comment: yeah, it works. I tried it earlier but folder structure was wrong. Thanks